# How to set font size of watermark in "pdfmake" javascript library

Tags: javascript, watermark, pdfmake

I am using [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org) to generate pdf in angular js.

I am trying to reduce/set same font size of watermark should be display in pdf, according to the dynamic text.

I have tried below config in , [playground](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html)

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
    ],
    watermark:{
        text:"Niklesh Raut",
         header: {
       fontSize: 22,
       bold: true
     },
     anotherStyle: {
       italic: true,
       alignment: 'right'
     }

    }

}
```

Also tried like below.

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
    ],
    watermark:{
        text:"Niklesh Raut",
        styles: {
           fontSize: 22,
           bold: true
        }

    }

}
```

But no luck.

**Question** : how to set/reduce font size for watermark ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Found below sample from https://itnext.io/angularjs-exporting-to-pdf-using-pdfmake-js-library-49f3afec97ef

```
    var docDefinition = {
              header: function() {
                    return [
                        {
                            style: 'table',
                            margin: [62,35,62,35],
                            table: {
                                widths: ['*', '*'],
                                headerRows: 0,
                                body: [
                                    [
                                        {text: 'Booking Summary', style: 'topHeader', alignment: 'left'},
                                        {
                                            'base64-image-string-goes-here',
                                            width: 150,
                                            alignment: 'right'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            layout: 'noBorders'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                footer: function(currentPage, pageCount) { 
                    return [
                        {text: currentPage.toString() + ' of ' + pageCount, alignment: 'center', style: 'footer'}
                    ]
                },
                content: [],
                pageSize: 'A4',
                pageMargins: [62,80,62,80],
                styles: {
                    topHeader: {
                        fontSize: 20,
                        bold: true,
                        margin: [0, 6, 0, 30],
                        alignment: 'left'
                    },
                    table: {
                        fontSize: 8,
                        alignment: 'left',
                        color: 'black',
                        margin: [0, 5, 0, 15]
                    },
                    header: {       
                        fontSize: 16,
                        bold: true,
                        margin: [0, 10, 0, 15],
                        alignment: 'left'
                    },
                    footer: {
                        fontSize: 8,
                        margin: [0, 25, 0, 17],
                        alignment: 'center'
                    }
                }
            };
          pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

`pdfmake` watermark fit to the page, even if length of character is 1, So added blank spaces to make word with a fixed length word, with below code

```js
var stars = '                                   ';
    var name = "Niklesh Raut";
    var center = parseInt(stars.length/2) - parseInt(name.length/2);
    var starsArr = stars.split("");
    var nameArr = name.split("");
    for(let i=0;i<name.length;i++){
     starsArr[center+i] = nameArr[i];
    }
    console.log('|'+starsArr.join("")+'|');
```

And use this for watermark

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
    ],
    watermark:{
        text:'              Niklesh Raut              ',
    }

}
```